# rviz2 dll conflic with zlib1.dll (Windows 10)

Tags: ros, ros2, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS 2 humble on Windows and followed all the dependency steps, and tested packages like turtlesim without any problems. However, when I try to use rviz2 by using the command "rviz2" or "ros2 run rviz2 rviz2", it gives me an error message that I need zlib.dll. I downloaded and moved it to the ROS 2 bin folder, but then it prompted me that I also need zlib1.dll. I downloaded it as well and moved it to the same folder, but then it gave me an error message saying that it could not initialize (0xc000007b).

I believe this error occurs due to DLL conflicts, but I am unsure which DLLs are conflicting with rviz2. Has anyone else encountered this error before? And if so, how can it be resolved?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413905/rviz2-dll-conflic-with-zlib1.dll-(windows-10)/) by [Proxeus](https://answers.ros.org/users/75451/proxeus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2023-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Accidentally, I used the wrong Version of zlib1.dll. Maybe this was the same issue for you @Proxeus.

Extracting [zlib-1.2.8-win32-x86_64.7z](https://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/64bit/zlib-1.2.8-win32-x86_64.7z) and adding its location to my PTAH variable fixed it for me.

---

Originally posted by [Soren](https://answers.ros.org/users/148223/soren/) with karma: 26 on 2023-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1